# Async await really waits a lot

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

```
public class GeoHelper
{ 
    const string GeoIpUrl = "http://freegeoip.net/json/{0}";
    private readonly string _ipAddress = string.Empty;

    public GeoHelper(string ip)
    {
        _ipAddress = ip;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetGeoAsync()
    {
        string uri = string.Format(GeoIpUrl, _ipAddress);

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return content;
    }

}
```

Then I am calling it as follows:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult UserGeo()
    {
        var ip = RequestHelper.GetClientIpAddress(Request);

        var geoHelper = new GeoHelper(ip);

        var response = geoHelper.GetGeoAsync();

        var result = response.Result;

        var resultobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoInfo>(result);

        return Content(resultobj.city);
    }
```

at `var result = response.Result;` it waits and never ends, i get a grey hair while waiting. I have a small console app it works fine there. same code.

Why? how can i fix?

Comment: Whenever you use `task.Result` or `task.Wait()` on a task has not yet completed, you risk deadlocks, and need to take steps to prevent them. You're blocking the thread until the task completes, but the rest of `GetGeoAsync` cannot run until that same thread is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, asynchronous child actions are not currently supported in MVC. Please vote on this issue ([CodePlex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/601), [UserVoice](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/3233329-support-asynchronous-child-actions)).

I explain the deadlock issue [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Essentially, it's because ASP.NET only allows one thread at a time in the request context, and when you block a thread in the request context (using `Result`), then any `async` methods that are attempting to re-enter that context cannot complete.

There are various hacks you can use, but the cleanest solution is to just use synchronous code if you can. Another solution is to use `Result`, but in that case you have to make sure every `await` in `GetGeoAsync` (and every `async` method it calls) uses `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which means you can't use the `HttpContext`, request, or response.

A third solution, which is rather hacky, is to use `AsyncContext.Run` from my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/):

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult UserGeo()
{
  return AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
  {
    var ip = RequestHelper.GetClientIpAddress(Request);
    var geoHelper = new GeoHelper(ip);
    var response = geoHelper.GetGeoAsync();
    var result = await response;
    var resultobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoInfo>(result);
    return Content(resultobj.city);
  }
}
```

However, the `AsyncContext` approach does not work for all code. It sets up a kind of "nested loop" but does not use `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, so some ASP.NET code does not like running within `AsyncContext`.

Comment: So basically, because the response object is not guaranteed to produce correct results if you have both a writer ( the asp worker process channeling data from IIS ) and a reader ( the user code, the ASpx page ) accessing it simultaneously.  As such, concurrent access is refused.

Comment: @AndyzSmith: That's not quite what I mean. When you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on ASP.NET, you're allowing any thread pool thread to continue the `async` method. So if you use request/response objects, you'll be accessing them from multiple threads (and they are not threadsafe).

Comment: Ok. So by using ConfigureAwait (false) the concurrent access is denied by isolating the response object to be available only in the first await.

Comment: @AndyzSmith: I don't know what you mean by "denied." If you have a question on how this works, please post a question.

Comment: Stephen. Asp.net is single threaded and any attempt to achieve multi threaded asynchronous behavior is going to be obstructed.  By the environment denying a second ( asynchronous ) thread access to the response object, ( deadlock ) or, or by limiting the scope of the Response context to the first await.

Comment: @AndyzSmith: ASP.NET is [most certainly *not* single threaded](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx), and it's not possible on .NET for a framework to deny access to an object when the code already has a reference to it (e.g., lambda variable capture).

Comment: thanks for the references and your forbearance.  I will look into the model as I am still not clear on these points.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public async Task<ActionResult> UserGeo()
{
    var ip = RequestHelper.GetClientIpAddress(Request);
    var geoHelper = new GeoHelper(ip);
    var result = await geoHelper.GetGeoAsync();
    var resultobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoInfo>(result);
    return Content(resultobj.city);
}
```

Comment: @DarthVader Why not? This answer won't compile (missing `async`, wrong return type), but can you not use `async` here at all?

Comment: Ah yes, I failed to check the return type of the calling method.  However "can't do that" isn't a particularly helpful response...

Comment: ok well that has another problem. I cant call that from a Html.RenderAction .